# Update values of certain dict keys in each row of a pandas Series

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

Consider the following Dataframe which has a Series `fruits` with rows of `dict` type. The goal is to update the `inspected` key with "yes" in each row and update the `quality` key value with the corresponding row value for `quality_after_inspection`. I've have achieved this using `enumerate` but I'm looking for a more pandas-like solution, more compact and perhaps faster too because the dataset is very large(50,00,000 rows). On profiling my code, it was observed that this for loop takes the longest amount of time.

```
In [2]: df = pd.DataFrame({'fruits':[{'apple':2, 'inspected': 'no', 'quality':''}, {'oranges':5, 'inspected':'no', 'qua
   ...: lity':''}], 'quality_after_inspection':['bad', 'good']})

In [5]: df.head()
Out[5]:
                                             fruits quality_after_inspection
0  {'apple': 2, 'inspected': 'no', 'quality': ''}    bad
1  {'oranges': 5, 'inspected': 'no', 'quality': ''}  good

In [6]: for index,elem in enumerate(df.fruits):
   ...:     elem['inspected'] = 'yes'
   ...:     elem['quality'] = df.loc[index, 'quality_after_inspection']
   ...:

In [7]: df.head()
Out[7]:
                                                  fruits quality_after_inspection
0  {'apple': 2, 'inspected': 'yes', 'quality': 'bad'}     bad
1  {'oranges': 5, 'inspected': 'yes', 'quality': 'good'}  good
```